Wronskian for nonhomogeneous ODE
For a second-order linear homogeneous ODE, the Wronskian of two solutions is either identically zero (if the solutions are linearly dependent) or never zero (if the solutions are linearly independent).
I am curious about what can be said for the Wronskian of two solutions of a second-order linear nonhomogeneous ODE of the form:
$$
y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = g(x), \quad g(x) \neq 0.
$$
If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two solutions of this nonhomogeneous equation, is there any analogous result or general behavior for their Wronskian? For instance:

Is the Wronskian identically zero or nonzero in some cases?

Does the nonhomogeneous term $g(x)$ influence the properties of the Wronskian?


Any rigorous results or counter examples would be greatly appreciated!

Is this what you mean https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx?

If $g(x)\neq 0$, the Wronskian of two linearly independent solutions can vanish at isolated points. Here is an example: $y_1(x)=1$ and $y_2(x)=1+\cos(x)$ are linearly independent solutions to the ODE $y''+y=1$. Their Wronskian $W[y_1,y_2]=-\sin(x)$ vanishes only at the points $x=n\pi,(n\in\mathbb{Z})$.

@Moo could you please elaborate a bit. I don't see any connection between Wronskian and Variation of parameter at the  moment

That shows that there is no difference between a homogenous and nonhomogeneous ODE when it comes to the Wronskian - other than the note of the previous comment.
